# Only checking first record, instead of all

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

EDIT: Update! Got the first part working.  However, I'm unsure how to also check for the other variables within the same IF() statement.  Can anyone help me with that?  The single if statement will refuse classes named exactly like the input.  However, I need it to also refuse Days AND Times that are equal.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Register Diver</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Aqua Don's Scuba School</h1>
<h2>Registration Confirmation</h2>
<?php
$DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];
if (empty($DiverID))
    exit("<p>You must enter a diver ID! Click your browser's Back button to return to the previous page.</p>");
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password")
    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
$DBName = "scuba_school";
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
    Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";

$TableName = "registration";
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
if (!$QueryResult) {
    $SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE registration (diverID SMALLINT, class VARCHAR(40), days VARCHAR(40), time VARCHAR(40))";
    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
        Or die("<p>Unable to create the registration table.</p>"
        . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
        . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Successfully created the registration table.</p>";
}
?>

<?php
$Class = $_GET['class'];
$Days = $_GET['days'];
$Time = $_GET['time'];
$DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];

$DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password");
$DBName = "scuba_school";
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
    Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";


$sqlString= "SELECT * FROM `registration` WHERE `diverID` = $DiverID AND `class` = '$Class' AND `days` = '$Days' AND `time` = '$Time'";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlString) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($DBConnect) . "<hr>\nQuery: $QueryResult");  
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);

if ($row["class"] == $Class)
{

echo "<p>You are already registered for $Class</p>";
    }

    elseif($row["days"] == $Days && $row["time"] == $Time)
    {
        echo "<p>There is a conflict with $Days or $Time</p>";
        }
else
{
 $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $TableName VALUES('$DiverID', '$Class', '$Days', '$Time')";
    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
    echo "<p>You are registered for $Class on $Days, $Time. Click your browser's Back button to register for another course or review your schedule.</p>";
}


mysqli_close($DBConnect);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query that says "find everyone with these details" then you say "if that found anyone = bad, else = good. For example:

```
SELECT ID FROM $TableName WHERE DiverID = '$DiverId', class = '$class', days='$Days' LIMIT 1
```

Then you run that query, if it found anything (`if(count($results) > 0)...`) then you show an error (or whatever) if it found nobody then it is safe to add the details.

**Bonus:**
As a side note, please look into PDO (`mysql_*` functions are [no longer supported](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) in PHP-land) and make sure you filter and sanitise your inputs before they go into Database queries (google for that,)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition after query is bad

```
//change this
if ($row['class'] == "$Class")
{
    echo "<p>You are already registered for $Class</p>";
}

//to this
if(!empty($row))
{
    if ($row['class'] == "$Class")
        echo "<p>You are already registered for $Class</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
SELECT * FROM $TableName WHERE `diverID` = $DiverID
```

You're querying the database for *all* records matching that `diverID`, ignoring the `class`. This means, for example, if some diver is registered to a different class the query might or might not retrieve that record. You want somethingl ike:

```
// this is for simplicity's sake only; please escape your input in your code!!

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $TableName WHERE `diverID` = $DiverID AND `class` = '$Class'"
$query = mysqli_query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    // already registered
} else {
    // not registered, insert
}
```

That being said...

1. **Don't** use `@` (error suppression). Turn off your error reporting in production, but  this (suppressing errors) is horrible.
2. **Don't** leave your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're not even attempting to escape anything, **and** worse, you're using `$_GET`, which also leaves you vulnerable to CSRF attacks.
3. **Don't** create tables on the fly. You should already have the table structure ready before the script is executed. If anything, they should be created by a setup script.

Comment: The problem is I need to do this for 3 variables.  The class one was the easiest I thought.  What if I made a i++ or something to go down each row? I'm not good at coding at all... and this is for class so I'm trying to go off of examples the teacher provided, but there is no examples of this.

Comment: I have updated my code, and cannot figure out how to get the other part to work.  Can you take a look?